# Java - Modulus - Adding from one table to another

Tags: java, jtable, row, modulus

I have a JTable of which one column is pre-filled with 30min time slots (6.30-24.00).

Now I have another table which has a list of movie titles which contains a column with the duration of the movie (in minutes - e.g. 140 minutes).

Now I have a button that does this. I made a piece of code, which funnily enough, sometimes works and sometimes doesn't (after I add 3-4 titles). It adds to the time slots according to the math equation.It gives me :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "DRAMA"
```

This is the code:

```
btnAddProg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        try {
                        int dur = Integer.parseInt(progTableModel.getValueAt(listTable.getSelectedRow(), listTable.getSelectedColumn()+1).toString()) / 30;
                        int durT = Integer.parseInt(progTableModel.getValueAt(listTable.getSelectedRow(), listTable.getSelectedColumn()+1).toString());
            if(durT % 30 != 0)
            {
                dur += 1;   
            }   

                for(int i = 0; i < dur; i++)
                {
                    String value = progTableModel.getValueAt(listTable.getSelectedRow(), listTable.getSelectedColumn()).toString();
                                        String value2 = progTableModel.getValueAt(listTable.getSelectedRow(), listTable.getSelectedColumn()+2).toString();
                                        channel1DataTitle.set(chOneTable.getSelectedRow()+i, value);
                                        channel1DataGenre.set(chOneTable.getSelectedRow()+i, value2);
                }
                                        chOneTable.repaint();
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException f) {

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                             "Please select a row in the Channel table!",
                                "Channel row not selected",
                                 JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


                        }


                    }
                });
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you click on the proper column and fails when you click on another, doesn't it? You have fixed logic (parsing the duration number) applied to a variable column (depending on the exact column the user clicked). Access the column with a fixed number, don't check for the selected column index.

Comment: And yes, it depends where I click. I had a previous button in which I had a similar problem, but I can't see how I can apply the same fix on this one too.

Comment: Replace `listTable.getSelectedColumn()+1` with the exact index of the duration column :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a String which does not translate into a number. It looks like the problem is you are working off of whatever the user has selected.  You either need to restrict the data you are processing to be from certain columns in your table, or validate the data before trying to process it.

Comment: Because sometimes, the user selects what you are expecting.  Other times, they are selecting something which is not a number.  If you look at the exception, it tells you that you are trying to convert the String "DRAMA" into a number.

Comment: You probably shouldn't do: listTable.getSelectedColumn()+1.  Instead, you might want to choose a specific column from the selected row.